# How to split API response which contains Ques and Answer in it. I want to split it in expandableListView android

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm beginner in android. I have ExpandableListView in which i have to show my response as Ques and answers. I have to split the answer where it contans "@@" symbols.
Below is my code

```
if (appState.isNetworkAvailable(FAQActivity.this)){
        networkRequest.invokeGetRequest(true, UrlConstants.getFAQs, FaqRootDto.class, new NetworkRequest.OnResponse() {
            @Override
            public void getResponse(Object obj) {
                    if (obj != null && obj instanceof FaqRootDto){
                        FaqRootDto faqRootDto = (FaqRootDto) obj;
                        faqlist = (faqRootDto).getResponse();
                        if (faqlist != null && faqlist.size() > 0){
                            for (FaqDto faqDto : faqlist) {

                                faqQuestionList.add(faqDto.getQuestion());
                                faqDataList.add(faqDto.getValue());
                                faqAnswers.put(faqDto.getQuestion(),faqDto.getValue());

                                Log.e("Ques",faqDto.getQuestion());
                                Log.e("Ans",faqDto.getValue());
                            }
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            faqAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
            }
        });
    }
```

For Answer value

```
    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.help_child_list_item, parent, false);
        }

        // FAQHelpDto faqHelpDto = faqDataList.get(groupPosition);

        TextView answerTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.answerTV);
        Log.e("faqAns",""+faqDataList.get(groupPosition));

        answerTV.setText(faqDataList.get(groupPosition));

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //faqExpandableListView.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the appropriate method: String#split().

```
    String response = "@firstuser@seconduser";
    String[] faqlist = string.split("@@");
    String part1 = parts[0]; // firstuser
    String part2 = parts[1]; // seconduser
```

And you use Collections in java for you application.

Comment: Where i need to place it? In oncreate or where?

Comment: where you have an string that you want to split.like

        String response = faqDto.getQuestion(); and it continues in my code in top

Answer (score 0):

For checking the symbol "@@" use: [contains()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))

For splitting you can use: [split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-).

```
String string = "Ans@@wer";

if (string.contains("@@")){
  String[] parts = string.split("@@");
  String part1 = parts[0]; // Ans
  String part2 = parts[1]; // wer
}
```

Comment: Where i need to place it? In oncreate or where?

Comment: It's just a way of splitting your desired target. So it's up to you, where, when and how you will use it :) You should use it while retrieving answers, check them if they contain "@@" and then split them if they do contain

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer. I have just changed my

`answerTV.setText(faqDataList.get(groupPosition));`

to

```
answerTV.setText(faqDataList.get(groupPosition).replace("@@","\n"));
```

Thanks for all for your responses